# jQuery.html() with leading whitespace and anchor tag in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, innerhtml

**Update: This question should be closed, as the problem was due to my own coding error and not really useful.**

I'm having problems with IE8 and jQuery.html() when there's a leading whitespace and an anchor tag inside.  To reproduce the problem, go here:

```
http://jquery.com/
```

Now enter this into the IE8 developer console:

```
$('body').html(' test<a href="">foo<a>');
```

You will notice that nothing gets printed on the screen.  Entering this in the console will confirm that the content of the body is empty:

```
$('body').html();
```

If I use the native innerHTML, this problem doesn't occur.  jQuery bypasses the native innerHTML for IE8 and instead uses jQuery.append() because IE8 would strip the leading whitespace.

Anyone know why this is happening? Is this a known bug?

Comment: Why is this whitespace is so critical for you? it does nothing you know...

Comment: I don't have an IE to test this in front of me but here are the lines of code to which he refers: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/support.js#L36 https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L226

Comment: You might also want to close your `<a></a>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your markup is invalid, it works if you close it,

```
$('body').html(' test<a href="">foo</a>');
```

I don't know how jQuery should handle invalid markup here though, so it might still be a bug.

Comment: I'm not sure undefined behavior on invalid markup can be considered as a bug. Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: Wow, thank you.  It was a huge oversight on my part. I'm going to delete the question because it's not useful for anyone else.

Comment: @JohnnyO, or we can close it as too localized, maybe it will help someone else who makes the same mistake. Your choice.

Comment: Frédéric, good suggestion.  I can't delete it because it's been answered, so I voted to close it.